# generate a report (if possible using SQL query) related to the setting of a Web Application in SP

Tags: web-application, web

I would like to generate a report related to the web application setting (url, port, Claims Authentication, application pools ... or let's say the main setting entered during the creation of a web application)  using a SQL query.
Any one have a simple SQL query for that ?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is inadvisable to query the SharePoint content and administration SQL databases directly.  Microsoft does not support this and you could put your farm in an unsupported state.

You can query this information using PowerShell (Get-SPWebApplication Cmdlet for instance) or with the server-side object model (i.e. SPWebService.ContentService.WebApplications) in C#.